# Testing REST API in SharePoint 2013

Tags: rest

I'm new to SharePoint 2013 and I'm looking to use REST to do some api calls to my other web sites.

I just want to see how to check and see the following items:

1. If the REST service is enabled on the SharePoint server
2. How to test the service to see if I can GET, POST, DELETE and PUT to a particular SharePoint site?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

[Postman API CLIENT](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

Excellent tool.

With Postman, you can construct simple as well as complex requests quickly, save them for later use and analyze the responses sent by the API. Postman can dramatically cut down the time required to test and develop APIs. Postman adapts itself for individual developers, small teams or big organizations equally well.

The new update looks like it has a bunch of new cool features, too.

But the fugly new UI is a deal breaker. It was extremely easy to use back then, but now it's just hard to find anything.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft documentation [has this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx) (along with examples in some standard languages, if it doesn't have yours Google it). REST is built in and unless it is blocked by firewalls or your user lacks permission.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a tool to test SharePoint REST API, best options would be:

1. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Try composer feature that lets you to make simple GET/POST request.
2. [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo). It is a add-on for Google Chrome with quite good and easy UI.

Answer (score 1):

REST API is by default enabled in SharePoint 2013. unless it is blocked by firewalls or user have not permission to access it.

To understand REST API in SharePoint MicroSoft has done great documentation with example. but if you want to go from the starch in REST API in SharePoint then

Go through this [Article](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/53/) from which i got reference to learn REST API in SharePoint

To Test GET,POST, DELETE and PUT you can use REST client to test them. Which also explained above Article.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the slide deck and demos from my [Introduction to the Client Object Model and REST API](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=B810A8A4579BD670%21718&cid=B810A8A4579BD670) conference talk to help you get started.

I also have a course on the same subject on Pluralsight.

Comment: Your tutorials are really awesome. I have started by tutorials on Pluralsight. Anyway, I have developed a REST Client for SharePoint as other REST Clients are not working seamlessly on SharePoint. Expecting a feedback from you. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd

Answer (score 0):

All tools (Fiddler, Advanced REST Client, Postman and so on) are very nice but I found passing `X-RequestDigest` or `FormDigestValue` is extra burden. So I have made [SharePoint REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) for seamless experience.

> Before using this extension, login or navigate to your SharePoint
>   site, then click on the extension icon. After few moment, you will get
>   some cool UI for making GET, POST, UPDATE or DELETE request.